# Android Switch Button error: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path)

Tags: android, button, widget, switch-statement

I'm working on an existing Android application that runs pretty well, and I'm trying to implement the Switch Button. The application has a theme with styles for the buttons:

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonMain</item>
<item name="android:button">@style/ButtonMain</item>
```

If I run my application and go to the screen with the Switch button, it crashes with the following error:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0e0011 a=1 r=0x7f0e0011}
```

The rest of the application runs well and the normal buttons are well styled.
If I comment the two lines from the theme for the button, it works well either for the Switch and Button.

My drawable resource exists as it's working for the button but not the Switch...
Does anyone has an idea? Is it possible to revert the theme for a specific widget? I tried with:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

but I still get my error, the Switch wants to get the button style from my theme.

Thanks!

Comment: Add your Java code for it. And also if you are using a getDrawable,then you must have a drawable in your folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same error.

I removed my "android:button" style which just pointed to an empty style that extended a holo style and this fixed it. I am assuming if extending android:button you will need to set some styles there.